# What is the difference in localhost (Apache server) and live web server

Tags: web-services, iis-7

I'm trying to host my site on live server, and it gives me an error.
But when I'm running that site on localhost it runs perfectly.
My question is what is main difference in live server and localhost server.
Any one please explain me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Live server , may have different configurations, that could be the reason why you get error, posting the error message would help you get an answer

Comment: 500 (internal server error) is the error. Thanks for your help, I'll check the settings/ configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference but might be you have not configured the settings of your live server. In localhost it takes the normal settings automatically. Please mention your error to have better solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you have not configured your conf files of the apache server that's why you have getting that issue. If you want any help you could contact me on the shubham.bansal1988@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends for your help. The problem is solved now. I made some changes in **.htaccess** file (rewrite rule), and it gonna works.

But I didn't get one thing that the **.htaccess** file on localhost is not working on live server. What is the reason, any one can explain. My server settings are same for localhost and live server.

Comment: .htaccess file is apache file. It wont work with live server because it wworks on node.